# widgets/js/widget.js not in static directory with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to resurrect the turtle module for the Jupyter Notebook (see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mobilechelonian), and have modified the imports in the header to read:

```
# from IPython.html import widgets, nbextensions                                                                                                                                     
from ipywidgets import DOMWidget # new                                                                                                                                               
from notebook import nbextensions # new                                                                                                                                              
# from IPython.utils.traitlets import Unicode, List                                                                                                                                  
from traitlets import Unicode, List
from IPython.display import display
```

The code now produces the following error when I run `from mobilechelonian import Turtle`:

```
[W 12:57:42.626 NotebookApp] 403 GET /static/widgets/js/widget.js (::1): widgets/js/widget.js is not in root static directory
[W 12:57:42.639 NotebookApp] 403 GET /static/widgets/js/widget.js (::1) 13.66ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb
```

I am running the Jupyter Notebook server in the mobilechelonian-0.2 directory created by unpacking the source, and true enough, there isn't a `static` directory there. Do I need to create one, and if so, what should the contents be? Or is there an environment variable or some command-line setting that will tell the server where to find what it needs?

Comment: Did you `pip install ipywidgets`? If so, did you do `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`? Unfortunately there's an extra step now to install the javascript needed for ipywidgets. There's a post-link script in the conda package that does this automatically so it's not necessary if you install ipywidgets via conda.

Comment: Thanks - I installed via anaconda, and `conda update ipywidgets` tells me everything is up-to-date.`pip install pywidgets` tells me `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipywidgets in /Users/gvwilson/anaconda3/envs/turtles/lib/python3.5/site-packages`. `jupyter nbextension enable --pywidgetsnbextension` says `Unrecognized flag: '--pywidgetsnbextension'`, and `jupyter nbextension enable pywidgetsnbextension` says `Enabling notebook extension pynbextension...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X pynbextension`

Comment: Hmm, how about trying to install ipywidgets from conda-forge? It looks like the default anaconda channel is still shipping ipywidgets 4.11, perhaps this issue is fixed in the latest version? Do `conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets`.

Comment: Do you have a mybinder demo of this?

Comment: I managed to get it working as is (though with warnings) on jupyter.cloudet.xyz . I also wondered whether it would make sense to tweak the display element so that it could be used as a tear-off, as in https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Variable%20Inspector.ipynb ?

Comment: Cool - can you please PR https://github.com/takluyver/mobilechelonian with your changes?